# Bootstrap drop down feature is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

Need help to resolve the bootstrap dropdown navigation issue. I followed all the rules available but I am missing something. Please help.

The service tab has two drop down li which should open when click on the caret. But the website css is not allowing to do so.

```
 <!-- navbar-header -->
        <div class="header-nav">            
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="navbar-header logo">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <h1>
                                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.example.com/">Brand Name</a>
                                </h1>
                    </div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 navis">

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/" class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom active">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/about-us.php" class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom">About</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="http://www.example.com/seo-service.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="http://www.example.com/seo-service.php">SEO Service</a></li>
                 <li><a href="digital-marketing-company.php">Digital Marketing</a></li>
              </ul>
        </li>



<li><a href="#projects" class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom scroll">Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/timeline.php" class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom">Timeline</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/contact-us.php" class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom">Contact</a></li>



                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact-bnr-w3-agile">
                                <ul>
                                    <!--<li><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="mailto:info@example.com">info@example.com</a></li>-->
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>000000000 </li>   
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>   
                </nav>
                            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your code functions as expected when you include the relevant CSS and JavaScript necessary for Bootstrap 3 to function. Did you double-check to ensure you're including the correct assets?

Comment: Yes I am using all of them. Still it is not working.

Comment: This is your code in Bootply: https://www.bootply.com/SOe9yfMT8w  The Services dropdown menu is working.  Now your HAMBURGER Menu doesn't work, but that's because you're trying to give two ids here: `id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 navis"`  ... `id=""` requires a single value.

Comment: Tried applying your code, but it didn't work. please check brandinnovac.com

Comment: Per the console when loading your site: `Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3`.

Comment: ok. How can I fix that?

Comment: Use for example the one that is used on the official Bootstrap website `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @PrashantGorule I would suggest re-acquainting yourself with Bootstrap 3s "Getting Started" guide: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/

Comment: I applied your suggested js file, but the error still remain.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

Here, `data-target` represents the div that is being targeted for toggling when you click the button. So, it is looking for the div with the ID "bs-example-navbar-collapse-1".  This line is fine, though I'd recommend renaming it to something more useful, like "site-nav" or something.

Now, here is where the problem occurs:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 navis">
```

This is the div that you are (correctly) trying to expand/collapse. But you have given it the id "bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 navis", which is not the same as "bs-example-navbar-collapse-1". So, you are clicking the button, but no div is being found with a matching ID.

To solve this, set the ID to "bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" instead (remove "navis"):

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

Now, all should be right in the world.

Also, far as the jQuery warnings mentioned above, it seems you are loading jQuery 2 already, so you don't need to include 1.12 as well. So make sure you are including the jQuery lib that you want.

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested, but it did not work. Can you check the website brandinnovac.com. See the service tab in the navigation bar. I have two dropdowns tab under it. It should open when click.

Comment: @PrashantGorule This code relies on Javascript to run properly. However, now you have an unrelated javascript error in the file `numscroller-1.0.js` on line 46. So it is possible this is causing other javascript to fail to initialize run. Resolve this error first. Also, as mentioned before, I would highly recommend removing the faulty jQuery import for 1.12.1. You can see all these errors if you check the developer console in your browser.